# Python zipfile and os

Tags: python, zip

I have some code to export all files within a zipfile to a path but what I want to do is create a new folder with the same name as the zipfile minus the ".zip" just like the windows explorer option does. I have commented out the code that doesn't work. It seems to be the os.makedirs that doesn't work.

```
 File "C:/Users/brentond/Documents/Python/Unzip all zip files in path.py", line 12
    Output = os.path.join(path, filename.replace(".zip", "")) # get new folder path name
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

the code:

```
import os, zipfile

# Define path of zip files to variable
path = r'C:\Users\brentond\Documents\TA2\HA GDMS'

for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(path):  # walk directory
    for filename in filenames:  # loop through files
        if filename.endswith(".zip"):  # find zip files
            filepath = os.path.join(foldername, filename)  # get zip file abs path
            #os.makedirs(os.path.join(path, filename.replace(".zip", "")) # create new folder same name as zip file
            #Output = os.path.join(path, filename.replace(".zip", "")) # get new folder path name
            ZipRef = zipfile.ZipFile(filepath)  # create zip file object
            ZipRef.extractall(path)  # extract all. This to put everything in the path folder
            #ZipRef.extractall(Output) # This to put the zip file contents into a folder with same name
            ZipRef.close()  # close zip
```

Comment: can you add the error message?

Comment: missing closing bracket `os.makedirs(os.path.join(path, filename.replace(".zip", "")))`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I should have realised that!

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this now and simplified the code a little

```
import os, zipfile

# Define path of zip files to variable
path = r'C:\Users\brentond\Documents\TA2\HA GDMS'

for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(path):  # walk directory
    for filename in filenames:  # loop through files
        if filename.endswith(".zip"):  # find zip files
            filepath = os.path.join(foldername, filename)  # get zip file abs path
            filefolder = filename.replace(".zip","")
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(path, filefolder)) # create new folder same name as zip file
            Output = os.path.join(path, filefolder) # get new folder path name
            ZipRef = zipfile.ZipFile(filepath)  # create zip file object
            #ZipRef.extractall(path)  # extract all. This to put everything in the path folder
            ZipRef.extractall(Output) # This to put the zip file contents into a folder with same name
            ZipRef.close()  # close zip
```